# I came up with my own version of "Cash" problem from CS50x, can I optimize it?

Tags: c, cs50

So basically, cash is a problem where you need to code a program that counts how many coins there is in a set sum.

For instance : for 0.41$, the minimum coins you can owe is 4 (1 quarter, 1 dime, 1 nickel, 1 penny).

The exercise will ask you just to code something that will answer : 4 for the entry "0.41"

I changed a bit the program so it answers for 4.2$ for example :
"16 quarter(s)
2 dime(s)
0 nickel(s)
0 penny(ies)" and was wondering if there is a way to optimize the code and make it better ?
Here is the code :

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <math.h>


int main(void)
{

//Prompt user for an amount of change
    float n;
    do
    {
        n = get_float("How much change is owed for : (in $)\n");
    
//Verify if the float is positive
    }
    while (n < 0);

//Multiply 'n' by 100 to avoid float imprecisions
    int cent = round(n * 100);

// Initialize the number of quarters (zero initially)
    int quarters = 0;

    while (cent >= 25)
    {
        quarters++;
        cent = cent - 25;
    }

// Initialize and calculate the number of dimes (zero initially)
    int dimes = 0;
    
    while (cent >= 10)
    {
        dimes++;
        cent = cent - 10;
    }

// Initialize and calculate the number of nickels (zero initially)
    int nickels = 0;
    
    while (cent >= 5)
    {
        nickels++;
        cent = cent - 5;
    }

// Initialize and calculate the number of pennies (zero initially)
    int pennies = 0;
    
    while (cent >= 1)
    {
        pennies++;
        cent = cent - 1;
    }

//Print the results
    printf("%i quarter(s)\n", quarters);
    printf("%i dime(s)\n", dimes);
    printf("%i nickel(s)\n", nickels);
    printf("%i penny(ies)\n", pennies);
}
```

Comment: Instead of looping one-by-one and counting, you can use division to get numbers of each coins.

Comment: It sounds like this belongs on [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @MikeCAT because I'm a total beginner in programming, I wish you could put some pseudocode to help me figure out what you said. Thanks in advance :D

Comment: @Kevin Hi, this is my first post and I'm really sorry if It doesn't belong here, still figuring out how stackoverflow works

Comment: For example you can use `quarters = cent / 25; cent = cent % 25;` instead of the first `while` loop.

Comment: And: don't use floats for exact problems. You'll end up with fractions of a cent.

Comment: @MikeCAT I'll try and do that :o) thanks a lot

Comment: @wildplasser the purpose of the problem is to use a get_float and the `int cent = round(n * 100);` to avoid imprecisions

Comment: You don't need to iterate for the 1-cent coins. You could make is *shorter* by having an array of available coin values, and a loop. This would also make it easy to modify so it works with other coin sets (UK for example has 1, 2, 5, 10, 20, 50, 100, 200).

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @MikeCAT, it'd be great to change it such that you use division and the modulo operator. This way, you'll avoid your while loop saving a few operations.  Further, as @Weather Vane suggested, you can also have an array of multiple coin values and a singular loop. It'd also be great to print the coins depending on what all denominations there are. It would also be nice to determine the number of denominations (`n_denomintations`) at runtime. The code for the same would look like:

```
int cent = round(n * 100);

int denominations[n_denominations] = {25, 10, 5, 1}; // coins in descending order, alternatively ascending order and iterate in opposite 
int n_denominations = sizeof(prices) / sizeof(prices[0]); // how many denominations of coins
int coins[n_denominations];

for (int i = 0; i < n_denomintations; i++) {

  coins[i] = cent / 25; // implicitly typecasts to int, meaning that quarters will get whatever value cent / 25 is, rounded down  
  cent = cent % denominations[i]; // will give whatever amount remains after removing quarters 

}

for (int i = 0; i < n_denominations; i++) {

  printf("%i cent coins: %i\n", denomintations[i], coins[i]);

}
```